# Is there a method/function in JS that fires promises one by one, synchronously?

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator, sequence, deferred

I mean, is there something like Promise.all, only where the methods are executed one after the other, in turn. Or is it left to make your own **custom method**?

```
const getUsersIds = (): Promise<any> => API.Users.getUsersIds().then(action((res) => (state.request.userIds = res))); 

const getUsers = (): Promise<any> => API.Users.getUsers(state.request).then(action((res) => (state.users = res))); 



Promise.all([getUsersIds, getUsers]) // - general row
```

In this case, the main order is, I have to wait until
**getUsersIds (1)** is executed, then based on the ids
of these users, get the user objects using the **getUsers (2)** method

Comment: Yes, its the `then` method on a promise or async/await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP

> ... the main question is, is there such a function in JS, I don’t always want to write an async / await function, I want something shorter and more convenient

Isn't it then, what the OP is looking for, the generic handling of an unknown number of promises (asynchronous functions) in a deferred sequence?

If this is the case one can achieve such a task by e.g. [turning a list/array of promises into an *async generator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#iterating_over_async_generators). The implementation should look similar to this ...

```
async function* createDeferredValuesPool(asyncFunctions) {
  let asyncFct;
  while (asyncFct = asyncFunctions.shift()) {

    yield (await asyncFct());
  }
}
```

The usage would look similar to ...

```
const deferredValuesPool =
  createDeferredValuesPool([promise1, asynFunction2, asynFunction3]);

for await (const value of deferredValuesPool) {
  // do something e.g. based on `value`
}
```

Running example code in order to prove what was said/proposed above.

```js
// a just example specific helper which creates async functions.
function createDeferredValueAction(value, delay) {
  return async function () {
    return await (
      new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay, value))
    );
  };
}


// the proposed helper which creates an async generator.
async function* createDeferredValuesPool(asyncFunctions) {
  let asyncFct;
  while (asyncFct = asyncFunctions.shift()) {

    yield (await asyncFct());
  }
}

// helper task which creates a list of async functions.
const deferredValueActions = [
  ["a", 2000],
  ["b", 3000],
  ["c", 1000],
].map(([value, delay]) =>
  createDeferredValueAction(value, delay)
);

// the OP's actual task(s)

// create an async generator ...
const deferredValuesPool =
  createDeferredValuesPool(deferredValueActions);

(async () => {
  // ... and iterate over it.
  for await (const value of deferredValuesPool) {
    console.log({ value });
  }
})();

console.log('... running ...');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

Learning from the above deferred-values generator-example on could come back to the OP's original code which due to its simplicity still is handled best by just another [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

But there might be cases where one has to chain an unknown number of async functions each relying on the result of the one called before. Thus one has to come up with a generic solution for *thenables*.

A possible solution was to just refactor the async generator function `createDeferredValuesPool` into `createThenablesPool` where the changes are minor ...

```js
// the OP's original TS code
// stripped and formatted into JS

// const getUsersIds = () =>
//   API.Users.getUsersIds().then(
//     action(res => state.request.userIds = res)
//   );
// const getUsers = () =>
//   API.Users.getUsers(state.request).then(
//     action(res => state.users = res)
//   );

// rewrite both above getters into (thenable)
// async functions which each returns its result.

async function getUsersIds() {
  // return (await API.Users.getUsersIds());

  // fake it for demonstration purpose only.
  return (await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, 1500, [123, 456, 789])
  ));
}
async function getUsers(userIds) {
  // return (await API.Users.getUsers({ userIds }));

  // fake it for demonstration purpose only.
  return (await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, 1500, userIds

      // prove that the `userIds` result
      // from the before API call got
      // passed to the next/this one.
      .map(function (id, idx) {
        return {
          id,
          name: this[idx],
        };
      }, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
    )
  ));
}

// the proposed helper which creates
// an async generator of thenables.
async function* createThenablesPool(asyncFunctions) {
  let result;
  let asyncFct;
  while (asyncFct = asyncFunctions.shift()) {

    result = await asyncFct(result);
    // debugger;

    yield result;
  }
}

// the OP's actual task(s)
(async () => {

  for await (
    const value of createThenablesPool([getUsersIds, getUsers])
  ) {
    console.log({ value });
  }
})();

console.log('... running ...');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wait for the first call to complete before making the second call - theres no magic/special methods needed here - it's just standard async code

```
const getUsersIds = (): Promise<any> => API.Users.getUsersIds();
const getUsers = (userIds): Promise<any> => API.Users.getUsers(userIds);

const userIds = await getUserIds();
const users = await getUsers(userIds);
action(users);
```

You can also do the same with the `then` syntax

```
const getUsersIds = (): Promise<any> => API.Users.getUsersIds();
const getUsers = (userIds): Promise<any> => API.Users.getUsers(userIds);

getUserIds.then(userIds => getUsers(userIds)).then(action);
```

Comment: As a rule, I do this, but again, the main question is, is there such a function in JS, I don’t always want to write an async / await function, I want something shorter and more convenient

Comment: @LevMyndra you want something shorter and more convenient than 5 lines of code?! Sorry, cant help you

Comment: @Jamiec I was thinking author is asking about scalable solution. This `then` chain could work for 2-3 promises, but what if you have 20-30? I doubt you are going to type all that chain with hands